# Get Queue Families in Vulkan Qt

Tags: c++, qt, vulkan

I am using the [QVulkanWindow](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvulkanwindow.html#details) example, trying to load an image and display it in the Qt window.

This sets up the Vulkan instance:

```
if (!inst.create())
    qFatal("Failed to create Vulkan instance: %d", inst.errorCode());

VulkanWindow w;
w.setVulkanInstance(&inst);
```

Now in `initResources()` of the VulkanRenderer class I want to get the GraphicsQueue from the device:

```
m_devFuncs->vkGetDeviceQueue(device, VK_QUEUE_GRAPHICS_BIT, 0, &graphicsQueue);
```

The error I get is:

```
vkDebug: Validation: 0:  [ VUID-vkGetDeviceQueue-queueFamilyIndex-00384 ] Object: 0x564e779a5f90 (Type = 3) | 
vkGetDeviceQueue: queueFamilyIndex (= 1) is not one of the queue families given via VkDeviceQueueCreateInfo structures when the device was created. 
The Vulkan spec states: queueFamilyIndex must be one of the queue family indices specified when device was created, via the VkDeviceQueueCreateInfo structure
```

Did Qt not set up the Graphics Queue? Or am I doing it wrong? Or should I create my own VkInstance and pass it to Qt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`VK_QUEUE_GRAPHICS_BIT` is an enumerant, not a queue family index. So that code is fundamentally incorrect.

The `graphicsQueue()` method of `QVulkanWindow` returns a `VkQueue` you can use.

Comment: It is a type error, practically. Shame that compiler does not stop this, as historically enumerant is implicitly converted to int.